# Primefaces LazyDataModel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to override the `load()` (abstract) method in `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel` class (from Primefaces JSF component library).

But my Netbeans IDE always complains as follows:

```
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

You may view the high resolution screen shot here: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/xihak

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ALT+ENTER on the class declaration line to have Netbeans automatically create the function template and see if it is different?

Comment: Alt+Enter is not doing much for me (not creating anything).

Comment: Have you tried to delete the method, then press ALT+ENTER? Or to delete the entire class, restart the IDE and re-create it?

Comment: I have done all possible efforts and spent a long time with issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel** *extends* **javax.faces.model.DataModel**

Yours is a netbeans java project first of all I doubt how you are going to use PrimeFaces in that.

In your libraries JSF library/jar is missing, you add that library and the error goes away.
Thing is netbeans is not able to compile the class due to missing class from JSF, DataModel and giving that error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right. The OP should create a project of type Java Web -> Web Application

Comment: @perissf being fairly new on Stackoverflow what OP stands for I have seen term used in many comments.

Comment: Means the user that posted the question. I guess it stands for Overflow Poster but I am not sure!

Comment: @gbagga The term OP is not unique to StackOverflow.  It means *Original Poster*, as in the *The Original Poster of the question.*

Answer (score 0):

What version of Primefaces are you using?  In Primefaces 2.2.1 the load method signature looks like this:

```
@Override
public List<T> load(int arg0, int arg1, String arg2, boolean arg3, Map<String, String> arg4)
```

There is no `SortOrder` so try changing that to a `boolean` and see if that helps.

Comment: it's Primefaces 3.0.1, you can see it in the Libraries folder of the screenshot

Comment: @perissf Oops!  How did I miss that?  Good find!